# Contextual action mode on top of action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, contextual-action-bar, actionmode

Recently I switched to the v7 Support Library to integrate Material Design elements.

Since then, my contextual action mode is displayed on top of my action bar instead of replacing it (like in another activity of my app).

- actionMode on top of actionBar
  [image: actionMode on top of actionBar]
- actionMode overlaying actionBar
  [image: actionMode overlaying actionBar]

I can't figure out why this is happening, because the code for starting and preparing the `ActionMode` are nearly the same in both activities. I always start them with `startActionMode(actionModeCallback);` and then inflate the menu.

If you need code samples, feel free to ask. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself: I didn't use the `ActionMode` version from the support library.